# Spring JPA scan user implementations of generic interface

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, reflection

I wanna write some starter for spring data JPA.
I have an interface on kotlin:

```
interface Converter<ResultType> {
fun convertList(values: List<String>): List<ResultType> {
    return values.map { convert(it) }
   }
    fun convert(value: String): ResultType
}
```

And scan of implementation of this interface from user(app which will use my starter) package to
Map < ResultType, implementation bean>.
My questions:

1. How do know which package I should scan(Ideally without asking user add some property)
2. And how to build Map i am thinking about using reflection. Have i other options?

May be some one knows how spring-data-jpa scans all repositories. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution.

```
@Configuration
class ConverterAutoConfig(private val context: ApplicationContext ) {

@Bean("converters") // this need because spring already creates bean with this type, but instead type name as key spring injects class name
fun convertersMap(): Map<String, Converter<*>> {
    val converters: MutableMap<String, Converter<*>> = mutableMapOf()
    val beansOfType = context.getBeansOfType<Converter<*>>()
    beansOfType.forEach { (_, converter) ->
        val type: String = (converter.javaClass.genericInterfaces.first() as ParameterizedType)
                .actualTypeArguments.first().typeName
        converters[type] = converter
    }

    return converters
}
}
```